# Excluding in-code comments from displayed code snippets in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, comments, python-sphinx

In our Python project, we extensively use in-code comments to tag team members or leave important messages for collaboration purposes, like so:

```py
...
with var_model:
    # FIXME: #38 make these arguments specifiable in the parameters.json file 
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000, cores=2)
```

While this practice is crucial for our development workflow, it poses a challenge for generating clean and focused documentation with Sphinx. Specifically, when including the code snippets in the documentation, we want to present the code without these in-line comments (i.e., anything that starts with #) to ensure the documentation remains clear and concise for the end users.

Is there a functionality within Sphinx or a recommended technique that allows for automatically excluding these comments from code blocks when generating the documentation? The aim is to keep the source code as is for developers but provide a cleaner view in the documentation itself.

Comment: A bit more practical detail to focus this problem might be helpful for getting answers. Are you open to any solution, or just vanilla Sphinx?  Can you add an example of the closest you've got to an acceptable solution?